# Backbone Underscore Template not working dash in variable name

Tags: templates, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

My backbone underscore template is not working. I got one variable return from the server with has a name
`month-total`. The template engine is treating as arithmetic operation of two variables. 
How to treat this as single variable.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the data and your template.

Comment: @idbehold: I'd guess that the data looks like `{"month-total":6}` and the template `<%= month-total %>`.

Answer (score 1):

Underscore templates work by converting your template to a JavaScript function. Things like `<%= x %>` go straight into that function untouched; then the function uses JavaScript's [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to make keys in an object behave like local variables. From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> By default, **template** places the values from your data in the local scope via the `with` statement.

You can use the `source` attribute of the compiled template function to see the JavaScript and if we do that with a simple template like `<%= a-b %>`, you'll see why it is treated as a subtraction:

```
// Reformatted for readability
function(obj) {
    var __t,
        __p   = '',
        __j   = Array.prototype.join,
        print = function() { __p += __j.call(arguments, ''); };
    with(obj || {}) {
        __p += '\n    ' + ((__t = ( a-b )) == null ? '' : __t ) + '\n';
    }
    return __p;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6rPnB/

There you can see the `with` and the raw `a-b` subtraction expression.

Now that you know what's going wrong, how do you fix it? Three possibilities immediately present themselves:

1. Fix the server to return nicer things like `"a_b": 6` instead of `"a-b": 6` in the JSON.
2. Map the incoming JSON to something friendlier when you load it or before you hand your data to the template.
3. Bypass the `with` statement using the (documented) `variable` setting.

For the last one, you'd modify the template to look more like this:

```
<%= data['a-b'] %>
```

compile the template with something like this:

```
var t = _.template(template_text, undefined, { variable: 'data' });
```

and then call compiled template function as usual. You don't have to use `data` as your name, you just have to make sure the template and `variable` setting agree.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eYn9m/